# Entity Framework 6: async, sync and transactions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, dbcontext

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and EF 6 and I have a controller that calls my service layer to perform some actions. One of those actions must be async so the controller can return a view before that action is complete. This is how it looks:

1. Controller action being executed.
2. Invoke Service.
3. Service performs some actions that save data in the DB.
4. Services starts a new task and return control to the Controller.

   (Task.Factory.StartNew(() => X())
5. Controller calls another service that tracks user actions. This
   is where it fails because the async operation I started on (4) uses a transaction and they are sharing the same DbContext.

How should I handle this?

**EDIT:**

I get an exception because the DbContext is disposed (the controller is disposing the DbContext after executing the Action.

I workaround this problem by creating a new service with a new DbContext but it's not the best solution. So, I call a method asynchronously and in that method I create a new DbContext surrounded by a using statement so it will be disposed after the async method is executed.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, a short yet complete reproduce of the problem would help. And please explain what *This is where it fails* actually means, an exception?

Comment: I added extra information.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate `ActionResult` for the step `4`, and call that action using a `HttpClient`.

This way it will re-create the `DbContext` (just like a new request).

```
1..
2..
3..
4
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    var url = "/Home/SecretAction";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(""));
    }
});
5..
```

Comment: This would work if the Controller was the owner of the async method. As described, the service has an async action, not the Controller. I cannot invoke a controller action from a Service for obvious reasons. I appreciate your answer but it is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, `2, 3 and 4` are all part of the `async` service? The controller itself is responsible of `5`? If yes, can't you put `2, 3 and 4` in `SecretAction`? because the controller itself doesn't need the answer back. If no, my bad, i didn't understood the scenario exactly

Comment: 2 and 3 are sync. When 2 and 3 finishes, 4 is started async.